# Javascript left-shift, does it operate on signed or unsigned integers?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, elm

I've got a unit test suite that never fails on my Windows dev machine, but it always fails on Debian in Travis CI. Both are running node v6.9.1.

It complains that `4294967295` is not equal to `-1`. The value `429496729` is generated by shifting four `0xFF` left by 0, 8, 16 and 24 steps respectively, and OR'ing them together, effectively making the value `0xFFFFFFFF`. The `-1` is the literal `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Is there something in the standard that says how this should work? Should my code result in `2^32-1` or `-1`? Is there at least something that says implementations should stick to signed or unsigned behavior, but not both?

The Elm elm-test test:

```
test "bytesToInts packs maxint ok" <|
  \_ -> bytesToInts [ 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ] |> Expect.equal [ 0xFFFFFFFF ]
```

The original Elm function:

```
bytesToInts : List Int -> List Int
bytesToInts ints =
  case ints of
    a :: b :: c :: d :: rest ->
      List.foldl
        Bitwise.or
        0
        [ a |> Bitwise.shiftLeftBy 24
        , b |> Bitwise.shiftLeftBy 16
        , c |> Bitwise.shiftLeftBy 8
        , d |> Bitwise.shiftLeftBy 0
        ]
        :: bytesToInts rest

    [] ->
      []

    _ ->
      Debug.crash "pack4"
```

which compiles to this:

```
var _elm_lang$core$Native_Bitwise = function() {

return {
    and: F2(function and(a, b) { return a & b; }),
    or: F2(function or(a, b) { return a | b; }),
    xor: F2(function xor(a, b) { return a ^ b; }),
    complement: function complement(a) { return ~a; },
    shiftLeftBy: F2(function(offset, a) { return a << offset; }),
    shiftRightBy: F2(function(offset, a) { return a >> offset; }),
    shiftRightZfBy: F2(function(offset, a) { return a >>> offset; })
};

}();
```

and this

```
var _user$project$Base64$bytesToInts = function (ints) {
    var _p6 = ints;
    if (_p6.ctor === '::') {
        if (((_p6._1.ctor === '::') && (_p6._1._1.ctor === '::')) && (_p6._1._1._1.ctor === '::')) {
            return {
                ctor: '::',
                _0: A3(
                    _elm_lang$core$List$foldl,
                    _elm_lang$core$Bitwise$or,
                    0,
                    {
                        ctor: '::',
                        _0: _p6._0 << 24,
                        _1: {
                            ctor: '::',
                            _0: _p6._1._0 << 16,
                            _1: {
                                ctor: '::',
                                _0: _p6._1._1._0 << 8,
                                _1: {
                                    ctor: '::',
                                    _0: _p6._1._1._1._0 << 0,
                                    _1: {ctor: '[]'}
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                _1: _user$project$Base64$bytesToInts(_p6._1._1._1._1)
            };
        } else {
            return _elm_lang$core$Native_Utils.crashCase(
                'Base64',
                {
                    start: {line: 83, column: 3},
                    end: {line: 99, column: 26}
                },
                _p6)('pack4');
        }
    } else {
        return {ctor: '[]'};
    }
};
```

Comment: What are “one” and “the other one”? All bitwise operators operate on and produce signed 32-bit integers in JavaScript except `>>>`, which produces an unsigned 32-bit integer. Your console test isn’t even using bitwise ORs.

Comment: @Ryan Paragraph removed. I'm only using `<<` and `|` here.

Comment: *“Should my code result in 2^32-1 or -1?”* Where is your code?

Comment: @Ryan updated. Didn't think I had to tell the whole story.

Comment: Turns out `0xFFFFFFFF` is parsed as a double, not as a 32 bit signed int. Still puzzled about why the tests succeed on Windows.

Comment: @FilipHaglund There's no difference between doubles and int for `0xFFFFFFFF` in JS. And yes, I'm puzzled as well how this test could succeed on Windows, the ECMAScript standard is quite specific on how bitwise operations work.

Comment: I'd recommend `(((a << 8 | b) << 8 | c) << 8 | d) >>> 0`. Or `new Uint32Array(new Uint8Array([a, b, c, d]).buffer)[0]`

Comment: Are you using a different version of the Elm compiler on Debian and Windows? The correct return value according to the current version of Elm is `[-1]` and I have no idea how the test would pass on Windows. (Are you sure the *test* in question is running?)

Comment: To expand on Ryans comment, I think JS Numbers are internally 64 bit double IEEE 754, but the bit-wise operators casts input to 32bit integer and outputs 32bit integers which at prior to subsequent operation or inspection are again converted back to JS Numbers. Such that x=8.3; y=x|1, produces a 64bit double y=9.

Comment: The test did run; changing the `0xFFFFFFFF` constant fails the test suite. I left the fuzz tests running, generating about 5 million values, and none failed on Windows. After OR'ing every `0xFFFFFFFF` literal with `0` it works as expected on both systems. The versions match exactly, and both are installed using the same command: `npm install -f elm@0.18.0 elm-test@0.18.6`. Furthermore, running some test values like `node -e 'console.log(0xFFFFFFFF | 0)'` works as expected on both platforms. Maybe some V8 optimization kicked in differently?

Comment: If it did, it would be a V8 bug (not impossible, but not the first explanation I’d reach for). To clarify: bitwise operations in JavaScript are well-defined; they’re not subject to implementation. That comparing with `0xFFFFFFFF | 0` (i.e. `-1`) gives the same results on *both* platforms when `(0xFFFFFFFF | 0) !== 0xFFFFFFFF` is pretty weird. Maybe it’s an `Expect.equal` bug…? Can you reproduce the behaviour without elm-test, or post a link to a GitHub repo?

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened here?

Comment: Nope, I sighed, commented out the test and left it. It's still that way today